# Add class element <li> number 6

Tags: jquery, html-lists, element

i have a list of items:

http://iceimg.com/i/ca/91/2580dcd0b2.jpg

I want to add a class to the list No. 8 and no. 6 .Is that possible?

Comment: also, you should think how do you generate the code. You can add the logic when you generate the codes

Answer (score 2):

Like this?:

```
$(".calendar li:eq(5)").addClass(myClass);
$(".calendar li:eq(7)").addClass(mySecondClass);
```

Or use this syntax:

```
$(".calendar li").eq(5).addClass(myClass);
$(".calendar li").eq(7).addClass(mySecondClass);
```

Or may be you mean `li` that contains text with "6" or "8" ? So use [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector:

```
$(".calendar li:contains('6')").addClass(myClass);
$(".calendar li:contains('8')").addClass(mySecondClass);
```

As @[Nix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/830134/nix) mentioned *"`:contains`" example will not only select "6" and "8", but also "16" and "18"* , so use it carefully! :)

Comment: would be better to remove the old class first

Comment: You remembered that JavaScript is zero-based?

Comment: @DavidThomas , of course you're right . i see you remembred that in css its one-based! :)

Comment: Remember, that your `contains` example will not only select "6" and "8", but also "16" and "18".

Comment: i am use :contains selector ,IF is zecimal number ? ((( http://iceimg.com/i/8c/0c/508bea90ce.jpg

Comment: @DimaBotezatu whats problem ? `$(".calendar li:contains('10')")` should work

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
$('li:nth-child(6), li:nth-child(8)').addClass('classToAdd');
```

If you use a jQuery selector (slower than CSS) or method it's important to remember that JavaScript indices are zero-based (so the sixth element in an array is at index 5):

```
$('li:eq(5), li:eq(7)').addClass('classToAdd');
```

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [CSS `:nth-child()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo).
- [`:eq()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/).